# How to add a start tag and end tag separately in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

so my question is how do I add the opening and closing tag separately using jQuery.

For eg.

```
<a class="test" href="#">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611165243857-d8b0ff81ba63?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDIwfDZzTVZqVExTa2VRfHxlbnwwfHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"/>
</a>
```

I want add a figure tag to wrap the image. So the outcome will be like below. Currently when i use the

```
jQuery('img').before('<figure>');
jQuery('img').after('</figure>');
```

it don't seems to work. Please advise. Thanks.

```
<a class="test" href="#">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611165243857-d8b0ff81ba63?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDIwfDZzTVZqVExTa2VRfHxlbnwwfHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"/>
    </figure>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `.wrap()`.

```
jQuery('img').wrap('<figure></figure>');
```

Link for more info if you want: https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score -2):

kindly check the below code.

```js
$( "img").wrap( "<figure></figure>");
```